# Best laptop specs for a better and faster numerical simulations

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, system-performance, computer-vision

Hope all is well! I am planning to buy a laptop (Windows) and looking for your help to decide the specs that we need to speed up the numerical simulations using Mathematica. The Mathemtica code I used usually need a lot of memory to find the results as it involve to calculate a huge matrix such that each entry requiring to calculate many numerical integrations. I am thinking of a iCore 7 processor, 8GB Ram and 512 GB SSD storage. 4 CPUs are enough?
For the processor, possibly a turbo speed of 3.60GHz for Intel Xeon 5118?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A new iCore 7 with only 8GB RAM! You're kidding. Mathematica wants RAM. A lot. (I can work quite neatly with 16 GB.)

Comment: That’s why I am consulting you guys! I am not familiar with the computer stuff.

Comment: Erm. I do not think that you can get laptop with a Xeon 5118. That's a server processor.

Comment: @Mutaz if you’re not overly concerned with having 8 cores, and you feel 6 might cut it, I personally use a Powerspec 1520 as my mobile workstation. It’s got a decent 6 core intel processor and the ram is upgradeable to 64gb (2x32gb of what is essentially MacBook ram). If that isn’t enough it’s got an 8gb rtx 2700 as well. I find it suitable enough ;) I haven’t been able to cause a kernel dump/reset from overfilling the usable ram yet. I’m not the most efficient programmer, of course, but I filled up 16 gb pretty regularly doing my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica as far as I've understood can do parallel processing...and does support some CUDA things.

> To use Mathematica's built-in GPU computing capabilities, you will
>   need a dual-precision graphics card that supports OpenCL or CUDA, such
>   as many cards from NVIDIA, AMD and others.

With that said however, the majority of things you'll do is probably singlecore stuff \

For large symbolic calculations, on my 16GB machine, I've actually run out of ram. So I can attest from personal experience, more ram is better, ideally lots and fast.

So basically, if your budget can handle it, the fastest CPU (probably 4c at the minimum...[can one even buy less than 4c nowadays?]) and ram you can get.

A dedicated video card would be nice, but not hugely required, depending on what you want to do.

If you check out the [recommended hardware](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html) page, you'll see requirements are quite modest at most.

Depending on what you do, if you solve an equation in 0.0001 or 0.00001 seconds...you arn't going to notice a difference.

I've been running my MMA on a macbook pro from 2013 for a while now, it still runs buttery smooth in version 12 and I've rarely done anything to max out ram or slow the software down...

My specs being:

- i5 2.4ghz
- 16gb 1600mhz ddr3
- intel iris

If you can do better or equal to that, I suspect you'll be satisfied.

Comment: Much appreciated!